# In Angular, How to read multiple selected checkbox value on change event

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular 2 application, In form I have input of type checkbox, which has possible multiple value. I want to read all checked values every time on change event, not sure how to do it. currently I can read only one value.

### template

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"> <small>checkbox</small>
          <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options" >
               <label class="container-vertical"> {{opt.value}}
                   <input type="checkbox" 
                          [formControlName]="question.key" 
                          [name]="opt.name" 
                          [value]="opt.key" 
                          [checked]="opt.selectedOption" 
                          (change)="onChangeValue($event)" 
                          (blur)="onChangeValue($event)"
                          > 

                   <span class="checkmark2"></span>
               </label>
          </div>      
       </div>
```

### component

```
 handleCheckBoxChange (event: any) {

    console.log(".............. ",event);
    console.log("selected Value ", event.target.value);

    var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
    var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
    console.log("question id", idAttr);


  }
```

Comment: Not sure if you are going for a reactive form or model driven form, anyways check [this cheatsheet](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-deal-with-different-form-controls-cheat-sheet-template-vs-model-4c77864cc16b)

Comment: can you upload your sample code on stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML should have two way data binding using ngModel.

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'"> <small>checkbox</small>
              <div *ngFor="let opt of question.options" >
                   <label class="container-vertical"> {{opt.value}}
                       <input type="checkbox" 
                              [formControlName]="question.key" 
                              [name]="opt.name" 
                              [value]="opt.key" 
                              [(ngModel)]="opt.selectedOption"
                              (change)="onChangeValue()" 
                              (blur)="onChangeValue()"
                              > 

                       <span class="checkmark2"></span>
                   </label>
              </div>      
           </div>
```

In your TS file you can check the `question` object's `options` property value which is going to be an array of Objects with properties(*name,key,selectedOption*)

TS file

```
 onChangeValue() {
  console.log(this.question);
  }
```

Comment: I have tried and getting this error, ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.

Comment: Can you share the cod eon stackblitz ?